# Shutdown taking a very long time (6+ minutes), hanging on specific process

Tags: windows-7, shutdown, process, group-policy, windows-domain

- Windows Domain (Windows 2012 r2 DC) environment
- Windows 7 64-bit client computer in question

I enabled the Verbose key in regedit so I can see what process shutdown.exe is hanging on, and it gets stuck, for 6+ minutes, on "Shutting down Group Policy Client service...".

Could someone point me in the right direction as to what is causing this? Anyone run across this?

Comment: I won't go so far as to say that is Normal, but I have seen a few machines like that in my days as well. Group Policy is what ALWAYS takes our machines longest to startup and longest to shutdown. Although ever since they added RAM to all of our PCs, I haven't seen any more of that. So potentially your computer just needs more memory. You might also want to check what Group Policies are being applied to the machine and your account; if there are a lot of them, they will take some time to apply. Group Policy may also be executing something, such as a script, which may be causing a delay.

Comment: You might want to try the diagnostics recommended in a [related post](http://serverfault.com/questions/33507/troubleshooting-windows-2008-shutdown-issue). Please share your findings.